# Bitrix Ошибка SMTP connect() failed при отправке форма заявки

Tags: php, ajax

When submitting the form, an SMTP error is displayed.
The code is in the attachment, the error screen too. Download new Phpmailer from github, tried it, it doesn't work either.

Has anyone coped with such a task?

```js
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");?>
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/mailer/PHPMailer.php");?>
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/mailer/Exception.php");?>
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/mailer/SMTP.php");?>
<?php
  $reqLoanSum = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['reqLoanSum']));
  $reqLoanCurrency = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['reqLoanCurrency']));
  $reqLoanPeriod = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['reqLoanPeriod']));
  $reqLoanAim = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['reqLoanAim']));
  $reqLoanFio = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['reqLoanFio']));
  $reqLoanPhone = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['reqLoanPhone']));
  $reqLoanEmail = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['reqLoanEmail']));
  $reqLoanAddress = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['reqLoanAddress']));
  $reqLoanOrganization = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['reqLoanOrganization']));
  $reqLoanJob = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['reqLoanJob']));


  $sandMail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
  //$sandMail = new PHPMailer(true);
  //$sandMail = new PHPMailer;
  $sandMail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $sandMail->isSMTP();                              
  $sandMail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.yandex.ru';                    
  $sandMail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
  $sandMail->Username = 'qqq@yandex.ru';               
  $sandMail->Password = 'qqq';   
  $sandMail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  //tls - тоже не работае                        
  $sandMail->Port = 465;                                 
  $sandMail->From = 'qqq@yandex.ru';
  $sandMail->FromName = $reqLoanFio;
  $sandMail->addAddress('qqq@yandex.ru');                    
  $sandMail->isHTML(true);               

  $sandMail->isHTML(true);                           
  $sandMail->Subject = 'Заявка на займ ';
  $sandMail->Body    = "<p>
                <strong>Сумма кредита:</strong> $reqLoanSum<br>
                <strong>Валюта:</strong> $reqLoanCurrency<br>
                <strong>Срок:</strong> $reqLoanPeriod<br>
                <strong>Цель использования:</strong> $reqLoanAim<br>
                <strong>ФИО:</strong> $reqLoanFio<br>
                <strong>Телефон:</strong> $reqLoanPhone<br>
                <strong>E-mail:</strong> $reqLoanEmail<br>
                <strong>Адрес проживания:</strong> $reqLoanAddress<br>
                <strong>Организация:</strong> $reqLoanOrganization<br>
                <strong>Ваша должность:</strong> $reqLoanJob
            </p>";

  if(!$sandMail->send()){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Ошибка. '.$sandMail->ErrorInfo.'</div>';
  } else {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Успешно</div>';
  }
?>
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/epilog_after.php");?>

    enter code here
```

Comment: SO is English-only. You can post in [ru.so].